# Group by optional column in slick (scala)

Tags: scala, group-by, left-join, slick

How can I group by columns in left-joined table? I need to do something like this:

```
val query = (for {
  (region, item)
    <- regionsTable.joinLeft(itemsTable).on(_.regionId === _.regionId)
} yield (region, item))
  .groupBy({
    case (region, item) => (region.regionId, item.createdAt)
  })
```

but this code doesn't work, because `value createdAt is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep...` So is it possible to group by these fields even if `createdAt`(i.e. whole `item`) is `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
val query = (for {
  (region, item)
    <- regionsTable.joinLeft(itemsTable).on(_.regionId === _.regionId)
} yield (region, item))
  .groupBy({
    case (region, item) => (region.regionId, item.map(_.createdAt))
})
```

*I added this `item.map(_.createdAt)` in groupBy*.

This however won't work (although it will compile) because you need to add some projection (this is how `group by` works in SQL - you can have in your projection either columns from group by or/and aggregated values.

The easiest way to change it would be like this (though you should rather add projection you need, probably you need some aggregation):

```
val query = (for {
  (region, item)
    <- regionsTable.joinLeft(itemsTable).on(_.regionId === _.regionId)
} yield (region, item))
  .groupBy{
    case (region, item) => (region.regionId, item.map(_.createdAt))
}.map { ((regionId, createdAt), _) =>
   (regionId, createdAt)
}
```

*I added last `map` after `groupBy`.*